# creating shared library using other library in linux

Tags: c, linux, linker

I have a shared library say "libeval.so". I am using this in my project to create on more shared library called say "lidpi.so". The library called "libdpi.so" is used by a tool. Now, this tool cannot see any other library other than "libdpi.so". I am using few function calls that are present in "libeval.so", and these are not present in "libdpi.so". Is there any switch in gcc, or something to overcome this.

Comment: i would expect no problems at all. the tool would link to libpi, and if libpi needs another library on its own, then it will care about loading it at runtime itself. the tool should not care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `libdpi.so` is designed so that it can open `libeval.so`, then your program only needs to know about `libdpi.so`.

Specifically, `libdpi.so` should have some function that calls [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), probably like this:

```
dlopen("path/to/libdpi.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Then other functions in `libdpi.so` can interface with `libeval.so`.

**Edit**: To build a shared library, use this command:

```
gcc -shared -o libdpi.so [list of object files to go in libdpi.so]
```

Note: When you build your objects, use the `-fPIC` command argument with gcc, like this:

```
gcc -fPIC -o foo.o foo.c
```

Comment: I am not sure how libdpi.so is created :(

Comment: Hi somehow, the following option's seems to be working :)
gcc -fPIC $(ALL_OBJ) $(ALL_PATH) -leval -shared -o libdpi.so
I will try to find an explanation :)

I also made some research on your suggestion. It is probably a nice method to load the library, I guess.